# Why sometimes when i run a program in terminal, it won't run in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, process, kali-linux, background-process

Suppose i have two applications called firefox and arduino. At first, I typed `firefox` to the terminal and i still can use the terminal as usual. But when i typed `arduino` , i couldn't use the terminal anymore and i had to put it as background process. So, What are the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the program is started. There are various modes in which an application can be started, a couple of them relevant to this question are Daemon mode and Foreground mode.

I think when you start your Firefox, the application by default is started as daemon, in daemon mode the application sliently starts running in the background so that no user interaction (just for an example) can hamper it.

More about Daemon [here](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Daemons#).

Another type is Foreground, when you start your Arduino application, it is programmed to start in Foreground mode as default (my guess).

Foreground mode does exactly what you mentioned, it just stays on the terminal until you kill it with CTRL-C or of some other methods. Foreground method is useful when you want to know what the application actually doing.