# Zookeeper systemd service is not running

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I have downloaded Kafka under `/opt/kafka` directory. I have created a user called `kafkaadmin` and added him to `wheel` group so that he can run as `root` user. Now, I have configured the zookeeper as systemd service and have created a file called `zookeeper.service` under `/etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.properties`. Below is the configuration

```
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kafkaadmin
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon /opt/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run the `systemctl start zookeeper` and then run the `journalctl -u zookeeper` I get a message stating the service exited

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2021-05-08 12:48:37 UTC, end at Sat 2021-05-08 12:55:59 UTC. --
-- Logs begin at Sat 2021-05-08 12:48:37 UTC, end at Sat 2021-05-08 12:55:59 UTC. --
-- Logs begin at Sat 2021-05-08 12:48:37 UTC, end at Sat 2021-05-08 12:55:59 UTC. --
May 08 12:48:47 kafka-node systemd[1]: Started zookeeper.service.
May 08 12:48:51 kafka-node systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 08 12:48:51 kafka-node systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 08 12:51:49 kafka-node systemd[1]: Started zookeeper.service.
May 08 12:51:49 kafka-node zookeeper-server-start.sh[2171]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /opt/kafka/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log due to Permission denied
May 08 12:51:50 kafka-node zookeeper-server-start.sh[2171]: log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
May 08 12:51:50 kafka-node zookeeper-server-start.sh[2171]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/kafka/bin/../logs/server.log (Permission denied)
May 08 12:51:50 kafka-node zookeeper-server-start.sh[2171]:         at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)at org.apache.log>lines 1-20at org.apache.log>lines 1-20
```

Now when I try running the `systemctl start zookeeper` I get the above error.
The `kafkaadmin` is a root user. How can I start the service with that user?
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "the process must not fork" for simple type services in systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604616/why-the-process-must-not-fork-for-simple-type-services-in-systemd)

Comment: Passing the `-daemon` flag to `zookeeper-server-start.sh` activates the ""dæmonization" mechanism" mentioned in the linked question. Remove it and your server will probably just work.

Comment: Updated the command with your suggestion. Now, I am getting permission denied error even if the user is a root user.