# I'm curious about the difference between running a daemon with a systemctl command and running it directly

Tags: systemd, systemctl, fork, snmp

I had a question while dealing with the issue related to snmp in my project.

If you enter the following command to execute snmpd with various options, snmpd will be executed without any problem.

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux mteTrigger mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid
```

However, in order to execute snmpd with the systemctl command, the service file below was created and tried to operate, but it failed.

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
After=network.target
ConditionPathExists=/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

[Service]
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=agentx
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As time went by to find the cause of the failure to execute, Eventually I came to the conclusion that the -f option should be given to execute snmpd with the systemctl command.

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
After=network.target
ConditionPathExists=/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

[Service]
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=agentx
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid -f
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid -f

I opened the man page to see the features of this -f option.

In the man page, the function of the -f option was explained in this.

```
-f      Do not fork() from the calling shell.
```

The meaning of fork I know is the action of a process replicating itself.

So?

I still don't understand the difference between running snmpd with systemctl and running snmpd directly.

I understand that systemctl's ExecStart declares a drive command (script).

What is the difference between declaring an executable to ExecStart and running it directly?

anyone help me?

Comment: [`Type=notify` is similar to `Type=exec` which is similar to `Type=simple`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). Then this question: [*Why "the process must not fork" for simple type services in systemd?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/604616/108618)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious difference is that once the service is enabled in systemd, it will start (and stop) automatically along with the other services on the host, e.g. at reboot. Its also possible to define additional behaviours within the unit file - you already have an entry to check for a configuration file before starting the service, and ensuring the network interfaces are up but other common ones are:

- restarting the service if it crashes
- applying a mask on the directories the daemon can read or write to
- capturing STDOUT and/or STDERR, redirecting this to (e.g.) syslog
- applying some cleanup actions when the service stops

Every daemon has its own set of command line options. They have different mechanisms for changing the behaviour while running (reload). The init system, regardless whether its SysV init, systemd, upstart, runit, openrc or something else, provides a consistent user interface for starting, stopping, querying and reloading the service.